# strange behaviour when using numpy array for ImageTK

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

I have three different ways to visualize a numpy array in an tkinter canvas. However, version `setNumpyImage` does not work. I cannot figure out, why this doesn't work, since all three ways are basically the same - in my opinion.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy

# simple gui with three canvases
class Gui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, height=100, width=100)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas2 = Canvas(self.root, height=100, width=100)
        self.canvas2.pack()

        self.canvas3 = Canvas(self.root, height=100, width=100)
        self.canvas3.pack()

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def setNumpyImage(self, numImg):
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(numImg))
        self.canvas2.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img)

    def setPhotoImage(self, photoImage):
        self.canvas3.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photoImage)

gui = Gui()

numpyImg = numpy.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(100,100,3),dtype='uint8')

#setting image directly
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(numpyImg))
gui.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photoImg)

#setting image via function
gui.setNumpyImage(numpyImg)

#setting photoImage
gui.setPhotoImage(photoImg)

gui.start()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Keep a reference for that could work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Check [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm#:~:text=The%20problem%20is%20that%20the,Tk%20to%20release%20the%20image.).In your example, you need to use `self.img = xxxx` and `create_image(image=self.img)`.

Comment: Thank you! I probably wouldn't have figured that out.

Comment: to close the Q shall i add it as an aswer?

Comment: Yes ____________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ist the answer provided by @jizhihaoSAMA.
The issue is documented [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm#:%7E:text=The%20problem%20is%20that%20the,Tk%20to%20release%20the%20image.).
Here is a copy of the text:

> When you add a PhotoImage or other Image object to a Tkinter widget,
> you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t,
> the image won’t always show up.
>
> The problem is that the Tkinter/Tk interface doesn’t handle references
> to Image objects properly; the Tk widget will hold a reference to the
> internal object, but Tkinter does not. When Python’s garbage collector
> discards the Tkinter object, Tkinter tells Tk to release the image.
> But since the image is in use by a widget, Tk doesn’t destroy it. Not
> completely. It just blanks the image, making it completely
> transparent…
>
> The solution is to make sure to keep a reference to the Tkinter
> object, for example by attaching it to a widget attribute.

For the question this means that i have to modify the code:

```
def setNumpyImage(self, numImg):
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(numImg))
    self.canvas2.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.img)
```